# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,32,239,239] and type float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to recreate CNN image recognition model from [this paper(model 1)](http://www.home.ijasca.com/data/documents/1_IJASCA_GPU-Based-Image-Classification_1-13.pdf) using different images. However, fitting the model returns me a ResourceExhaustedError at the first epoch. The batch size is already considerably small so I'm guessing the problem is with my model definition which I've copied from the paper. Any advice on what to change with the model will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
#Load dataset
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_SIZE = (244,244)
train_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_dir, 
    shuffle = True,
    image_size = IMG_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
val_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    main_dir, 
    shuffle = True, 
    image_size = IMG_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
class_names = train_set.class_names
print(class_names)

#Augment data by flipping image and random rotation
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
])

#Model definition 
model = Sequential([
    data_augmentation,
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
    Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(4,4), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4,4)),

    Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    Flatten(),
    
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(128, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(1, activation='softmax')

])

model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

history = model.fit(train_set,validation_data=val_set, epochs=150)
```

Error after fitting model:

```
ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,32,239,239] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node gradient_tape/sequential_1/average_pooling2d/AvgPoolGrad (defined at <ipython-input-10-ef749d320491>:1) ]]
```

nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1938MiB /  2004MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       959      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 97MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1270      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               25MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4635      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          212MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5843      C   /usr/bin/python3                 1595MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What batch size are you using? Did you try a batch size of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by your GPU running out of memory. This could be either because 1) you're loading too much data per epoch even for your GPU, or 2) if you happen to have enough VRAM, another process reserves some memory between epochs. This might happen because tensorflow reserves 100% of VRAM at runtime. [You can limit amount of VRAM reserved to just what's needed.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)

```
import tensorflow as tf
for gpu in tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

Edit: Looking at your graphics card, I'm fairly certain you don't have enough VRAM for your batch size and input size (so problem 1). You should lower your batch size.